# Firebase Data retrieval to string

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

I have been trying to get data into string for almost 5 hours now. I have referred the previous questions related to the same and tried doing it but not able to store the data into a string.

This is the code snippet I am working on:

```
@Override
public void Click(String name) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Club_Screen").child(name);
    Log.d("Name", name);

    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String insta = snapshot.child("instagramLink").getValue().toString();
                String github = snapshot.child("github").getValue().toString();

                if (insta != null) {
                    Log.d("Insta", insta);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Insta", "Instagram link is null");
                }

                if (github != null) {
                    Log.d("Github", github);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Github", "GitHub link is null");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           Log.d("Error",databaseError.getMessage());

        }
    });
}
```

[This is the Log Message I am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw4Qs.png)

[This is the realtime database for my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov6i0.png)

I am expecting to store the links from database to strings so that I can redirect the app to that particular link.

**Answer To the Question**

```
@Override
public void Click1(String name) {
    DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference reference = root.child("Club_Screen");
    com.google.firebase.database.Query query = reference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(name);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String github = (String) snap.child("github").getValue();
                gotoUrl(github);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is quite a lot of code, you might want to consider stripping it down to as few lines of code as possible. This would help people, including you, to narrow down where the problem is. Also, it would be good if you could include the error you get, and at what line you expect to get a string. There's good information over at [Minimal, Reproducible Example](Minimal, Reproducible Example)

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. At a minimum, please add `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I added the Log.d("Error",databaseErrror.getMessage()); and I didn't got any errors for this log but for something else that I don't know of. Please Look into this also.

Comment: @AlexMamo The thing is I am getting name from my database but not the text present in instagramLink or github.

Comment: So you want to read the data of a single element, for example, `c1`? Or of all elements?

Comment: @AlexMamo I wanted only the link present in instagramLink child. By the way I did some changes and its working right now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MeetModi Good to hear that you were able to solve your own problem. Can you post the solution as an answer below, rather than including it in your answer? That ensure the system knows that the question has been answered, allows you to accept it, and makes it more likely that others can benefit from your experience in the future.